# Optimal display for overlapping series in a line chart

Tags: data-visualization, highcharts

In a context of a line chart displaying time data in regular intervals where multiple series might overlap what would be the optimal way to:
A) hint the user that the chart has overlapping series?
B) give the user the capability to visualize all those series? Like spanning the series somehow?

Answer (score 1):

For overlapping series in a line chart, I would keep the traditional line chart but put a label at the end of the graph with a color legend.  The legend and label will help the user get information quickly.

> [image]

Another version of a line chart for overlapping series can be a line area chat.

> [image]

If you are not stuck on only line charts, I would suggest a bar chart.  Below are some examples that you can use.

Example 1:
[image]

Example 2:
[image]

Example 3:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are couple ways to indicate that there are overlapping series on a chart. You can increase the `marker` radius of one of them. The number of legend elements tells you how many series there is, too. Finally, you can distribute series on a different yAxis, with different `top` and `height` properties. Also, in styled mode, when you hover on legend item, other series opacity changes.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.marker.radius

Examples:
http://jsfiddle.net/whsgpdyw/ - changing marker radius
http://jsfiddle.net/fuq6j4sg/ - each series on a different yAxis

Comment: Thanks for the options. Unfortunately, the marker can't be an option because of the performance degradation in the chart. 
The series are being computed and split between two different yAxis. Most of the times the overlapping series are in the same yAxis.
Although, I wasn't aware of that yAxis positioning portrayed in the second exampled. Maybe if I pre-determine the overlapping series before the yAxis assignment I'll be able to setup more yAxis positioned in different ways to make sure the overlapping series are all in distinct yAxis.